# What OST is playing?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

I wanted to know is somebody knows what OST is playing in the anime "Boku no hero Academia" in S3E23 at 11:00. It seems to be the beginning of the Track "United States of Smash" but it sounds different and I can't seem to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The song at 11:00 in S3E23 is called AllMight with UA Students which is basically United States of Smash. [I think this is the song that your looking for](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJgTQvhUiYs)